# How to get current user information from REST API in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there any endpoint in Azure DevOps I can use to get details about current user in JSON knowing only his/her token?

I tried following endpoints:

- `https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users` requires user descriptor;
- `https://aex.dev.azure.com/_apis/User/User` doesn't accept token;
- `https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/profile/profiles/me`  doesn't accept token neither;
- `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_usersSettings/about` is the best I could find, but since it returns HTML it isn't perfect neither.

Any ideas?

Comment: `curl -u :{PAT} https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/connectionData | jq`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the details of the current user using the authorization token by sending an authenticated `GET` request to `<baseurl>/_apis/ConnectionData`. Tested on Azure DevOps Services and Server (TFS).